Why must field lines inside a cavity begin and end at the cavity walls?
In his proof that the electric field inside an empty cavity within a conductor is 0, Griffiths claims the following:

If a cavity surrounded by conducting material is itself empty of charge, then the field within the cavity is zero. For any field line would have to begin and end on the cavity wall, going from a plus charge to a minus charge


I am unable to understand why exactly must the electric field line through a point start and end at the cavity walls. I know that it can't start and end at the same point since the curl of $\vec{E}$ is $0$. But why is it not possible for the field to start and end at two points within the cavity itself?

It is because $\nabla \cdot {\bf E} = \rho / \epsilon_0$. This implies that at any location where there is no charge density ($\rho=0$) the field lines cannot end or begin but must pass through.
The other notable property of electric field lines follows from another Maxwell equation: $\nabla \times {\bf E} = - d{\bf B}/dt$. This leads to $\nabla \times {\bf E} = 0$ in the static case. It follows that you can't have an electric field line forming a closed loop in the static case. If there was one then you could do the integral
$$
\oint {\bf E} \cdot d{\bf l}
$$
around the loop and get a non-zero answer. But by Stokes' theorem that integral is equal to $\int \nabla \times {\bf E}\, dS$ over a surface bounded by the loop, and this must be zero in the static case.

That makes sense. Could you also explain why we can be sure that the electric field lines WILL necessarily begin and end somewhere? Why is it not possible for them to indefinitely loop around within the cavity?

I added a paragraph to deal with this part

I assume you're asking about a closed field line within the cavity, correct? Similar to the field lines of a magnetic field. But this can't happen because $\nabla \times\mathbf{E}=0$ and $\oint_C \mathbf{E}\cdot d\vec{l}=0$. If the electric field lines close in on themselves like magnetic field lines then the curl of the electric field is not zero, similar to the curl of the magnetic field not being zero. But since the curl is always zero in the static regime, there can be no closed electric field lines within the cavity - the field is zero.
Adding to this, when $\partial \mathbf{B}/\partial t  \neq0$ then you may get closed electric field lines just like the ones from a magnetic field. The simplest case is a linearly increasing magnetic field - the field lines are mathematically identical to the ones of a magnetic field around a stationary current.

But how does electric field lines not closing in on themselves imply that they must start and end at the cavity walls? This might be a stupid question but why is it not possible for the ends to indefinitely loop around in the cavity, never meeting eachother or the cavity walls?

Like in a spiraling motion? Those electric field lines are just a representation of the vector field, which has a value for every point in space. Meaning every closed line has an electric field value for every point and its curl wouldn't be zero.
